# I'm trying to generate an xml output from several xml files

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a toplevel "index" file that may or may not have an element listing a series of additional files.  All of the files are in xml format, but have an extension like ".exlog".  First question, can the xsl function document() handle a uri for a file that is xml, but does not have the xml extension?  I can't find documentation online for this.

I've gone ahead and resaved the files to have a .xml extension just in case, and I've saved the files to the same directory.  My XSL file has the section below, and everything works EXCEPT for all of the calls to the document function - those always return nothing:

```
   <xsl:template match="tasktype">
   <xsl:if test="looptask">
    <Row>
        <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">
            <xsl:value-of select="looptask/@label"/>
        </Data></Cell>

        <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">
            <xsl:value-of select="looptask/taskinfo/definition"/>
        </Data></Cell>

    </Row>
    <xsl:for-each select="looptask/looplogs/looplog">
    <xsl:variable name="loopFile" select="document('source.xml')/results/iteration"/>
    <Row>
        <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">
        <xsl:value-of select="@path"/>
        </Data></Cell>
        <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">
        <xsl:value-of select="$loopFile"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="document('source.xml')/results/iteration"/>
        </Data></Cell>
    </Row>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

The source.xml file looks like the code below, and I'm running the rest of the xsl on a parent xml file.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<results>
<iteration value="F19">help!</iteration>
<tasktype>
    <task label="task1">
        <taskinfo>
            <definition>text</definition>
        </taskinfo>
    </task>
</tasktype>
<iteration_results status="Fail"/>
```

It doesn't matter what I do, I cannot get the document function to return any information.  I feel like I must be missing something obvious.

FWIW, I'm using notepad++ to run the transform file on the master xml document.

Answer was provided (thank you!) which is that the full path is needed.

Now I have a follow-up question. I'm using XSLT 1.0 and my source file has several node sets like this:

```
    <tasktype> 
    <task label="task1"> 
    <taskinfo> <definition>text</definition> 
    </taskinfo> </task> </tasktype>
```

And I want to select each definition and print the text for each... how can I do that?  I thought I could assign a variable the node set by using copy-of, but I can't figure out how to select the nodes in that variable.  Is it not possible with XSLT 1.0?

Comment: Are there any namespaces involved that you haven't shown?

Comment: No - only xsl namespace is being used.

Comment: @nick There is nothing in your code (as far as I can see) that would cause the issue. Are you sure your processor is conforming to the XPath/XSLT specifications? What happens if you just ask for `<xsl:copy-of select="document('')"/>`?

Comment: It's hard to say what's wrong unless you publish your actual files (or, better yet, a minimal reproducible example). May be notepad++ has a different idea about the current working directory than you think it does. Try supplying the fully qualified path to `source.xml`.

Comment: It looks like the fully qualified path is needed, and now I'm able to get the value of a node (element or attribute) that has text (example "<xsl:value-of select="document('fullpath/source.xml')/results/iteration/@value" /> works).

Now I have a follow-up question.  I'm using XSLT 1.0 and my source file has several node sets like this:
        <tasktype>
    <task label="task1">
        <taskinfo>
            <definition>text</definition>
        </taskinfo>
    </task>
</tasktype>
And I want to select each definition and print the text for each... how can I do that?

Comment: @nick I suggest you ask your additional question separately. With a full [mcve].